# Using inline expression with SessionParameter fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatasource

This works as fine in my ASP.NET page's SqlDataSource:

```
<asp:SessionParameter Name="FromTimestamp" SessionField="fromtime" DefaultValue="2/22/2012" />
```

Why does this produces error: `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

```
<asp:SessionParameter Name="FromTimestamp" SessionField="fromtime" DefaultValue='<%=DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()%>' />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy")
```

Will get you the format you already know works.

Comment: you're right. I don't understand why, however, that in Page_Load SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["FromTimestamp"].DefaultValue = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString(); works though...